# IIS Rewrite Regular Expression rule

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am using IIS 7's URL Rewrite module. I have a rule where I am trying to say, if the url matches `/news/<anything but the word "article">`

```
<match url="news/([^/]+)"/>
```

How can I acheive this?

thanks
higgsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a negative lookahead:

```
news/(?!article)([^/]+)
```

The (?!...) part says "fail if ... matches" (but don't consume the characters).

Comment: Hi MRAB - thats perfect, however can I be cheeky and ask for one other thing. I actually need the following:

/news/<anything but the word "article"><and not when there is the string "/Action" after the last section*> So I would want to match /news/article1 but not /news/article1/action and not /news/article1/action/edit